# Can I start Eclipse headless build programmatically - not via console?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, rcp, headless

I need to start a headless build of an eclipse rcp project, but I don`t want to start it using "eclipse --launcher.suppressErrors -nosplash -application org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.headlessbuild -data /tmp/workspace -build all" for example.

So is it possible to do it programmatically, without using the console?

Best Regards,
Simeon Angelov

Comment: Whats wrong with using the console in the first place?

Comment: Well, my application is made with GUI, and it includes building of project with GUI. I need to implement new feature which is the building of project but this time headless, using some plugins from the main application. 
The headless building will be started as a service from remote machine.

I already made some restrictions in the application so I know whether a standard or a headless build is running, so I just restrict the GUI part if it`s headless. The problem is that in some moment in the process of headless building the cdt plugin starts some GUI things which are not under my control.

Comment: From the other side my afraid is that if I use the console way probably I will not be able to execute all the source code needed to prepare the data for the building process. So I left this method for the last solution and I was wondering if it is possible to start the headless build programatically?
I wanted to check it first before to run command line things.

Comment: If you have eclipse source code, you can reference eclipse as a library and call it like any other piece of code (in theory, because eclipse is not 100% written in java) If you don't have the source code the only way to start another process/application is by using Runtime#getRuntime().exec("eclipse <params>");